# How can I print a variable returned from a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have this function:

```
function findAddressViaGoogle(address){
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            return results[0].formatted_address;
        } else {
            console.log("Unable to find address: " + status);
        }
     });
}
```

How can I print the returned value from this function?

if i do:

```
$('#location-suggest').text('Do you mean <a>'+findAddressViaGoogle($(this).val())+'</a> ?');
```

it prints undefined

Comment: What do you mean by "print" exactly? Are you using this function in the context of a web site? Are you just using this in some JavaScript that you are running? More information would be helpful.

Comment: nope i mean i can use $('#element').text(findAddressViaGoogle());

Comment: Instead of `return results[0].formatted_address` you can just make it `$('#element').text(results[0].formatted_address);`

Comment: ok, but i'm talking about print that result returned OUT of the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback is being called somewhere inside the `Geocoder()` and its return value is not received inside your `findAddressViaGoogle()` function.

**You can initialize a variable an pass the value to it:**

```
function findAddressViaGoogle(address){
  var address = "";
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      address = results[0].formatted_address;
    } else {
      console.log("Unable to find address: " + status);
    }
  });

  return address;
}

var myAddress = findAddressViaGoogle('foobar');
alert(myAddress);
```

Also, keep in mind that you have to call a function before it can return anything.

**So to pass the collected value:**

```
$('#myElementID').html(findAddressViaGoogle('foobar'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write)?

Comment: nope i mean if i can use $('#element').text(findAddressViaGoogle());

Comment: yes, you can AFAIK. It is just a string (if you return something that is; there's a problem, you don't always return)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$(".putYourSelectorHere").html(findAddressViaGoogle())
```

replace `.putYourSelectorHere` with your selector (`#output` for example). If you want to print your result in the body use `body` selector:

```
$("body").html(findAddressViaGoogle())
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: +1 as you finished writing before I even started.. Also, `.html` will work if the elements accepts this method (`span`/`div`/`p`/etc), now if OP wants to output it in a `textarea`/`input`, use `.val` instead.

Comment: Was just adding a note as OP didn't specify which kind of element he wanted to output the function's return to, your answer is the correct one. =]